# Как будет правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Был даже момент, когда я рассказал (,) чем закончилась «Ирония судьбы».

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

(1) Был даже момент, (2) **когда** я рассказал, (3) **чем** закончилась "Ирония судьбы".

СПП состоит из главного предложения и двух придаточных (последовательное подчинение).

Когда - союзное слово, чем - союзное слово, между предложениями ставятся запятые.

Вид придаточных: придаточное определительное (такой момент, в который/когда) и придаточное изъяснительное (рассказал, чем)